# Use "Encoding > Convert to ..." as a macro in Notepad++

Tags: encoding, macros, notepad++

I tried to record the action of **Encoding > Convert to ANSI** and save it as a macro so that I can copy and add the its code to another macro.
This is the recorded code:

```
<Macro name="convert to ANSI" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="0" message="2004" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2179" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2025" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2422" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2325" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

If I run it in a file, the output is the code itself (or a few lines from another macro saved in shortcuts.xml), just overwrites the original contents of the file.
Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using the NppExec plugin available from the PluginManager, then you could use this simple NppExec Script:

```
 NPP_MENUCOMMAND Encoding/Convert to ANSI
```

Just use Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute... , enter the script, either hit OK or save it for later reuse. (The script is saved in the file `npes_saved.txt` . You find this file in the `plugins\Config` subdirectory either in your users Notepad++ path or in the installation directory of Notepad++).

**Create a keyboard shortcut for the script**

1. You can save the script with the `Save...` button in the dialog: [image: Execute Dialog with Save... Button].
2. Once the script has a name, you can go to the Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options Dialog and associate the *script name* with an *Item name* and add the *Item name* to the menu, see the lower left part in this picture. [image: Advanced Options Dialog].
3. Restart Notepad++
4. Now you find the *Item name* in the Settings -> Shortcut Mapper... Dialog somewhere on the plugins panel. Here you can connect the script with a keyboard shortcut for easy access.

Comment: Thank you! I added a lines to it and now I can string several actions together. `NPP_MENUCOMMAND: Encoding/Convert to ANSI
NPP_MENUCOMMAND: Macro/ENTITY TO SYMBOL`
Does it have a command to save the file?

Comment: @RomanA.S. added some more info to the answer, hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!